# ERROR while activating Append structure in EKPO

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I added an append structure in table `EKPO` via `SE11`. I have these errors while activating, table `EKPO` is inactive .
[image]

and I can't adjust the table via transaction `SE14`.

[image]

[image]
the appended structure is not seen in `SE11`,

but I can see the field in transaction `DB02`,

[image]

I want to cancel all the updates and get an active version of the table, system generate a lot of dumps now and we can not work on the system, I deleted the appended structure but the errors still exist.

I am ABAP developer with a basis background.

Any proposed solution ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check SAP note [2030146](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2030146). One of the enhancement structures you have must be marked as "randomly enhanceable" which collides with the enhancement category of `EKPO` table which is at most "can be enhanced *character-type" or "numeric".

Comment: `I want to cancel all the updates and get an active version of the table` try to regenerate the DB table with SE14 transaction, this should help